# PointAnimation on Path and BezierSegment

Tags: c#, animation, windows-store-apps

I ran into a problem. I'm trying to animate a simple Path with PointAnimation. I have a working solution for WPF, and I tried to use it in my Metro app. However it's syntactically correct, it doesn't do anything. What I missed? What I need to change in my XAML?

```
       <Path Stroke="DarkMagenta" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                        <BezierSegment x:Name="bezierSegment1" Point1="100,0" Point2="100,200" Point3="200,200" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>

            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bezierSegment1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point1" From="0,0" To="100,0" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bezierSegment1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point2" From="0,0" To="100,200" />
                        <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bezierSegment1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point3" From="0,0" To="200,200" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
```

I tried to put the storyboard into resources and begin outside from a Button_Click handler, but it doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes,yes.

> EnableDependentAnimation is an important property to animations that allows you to animate your custom dependency properties. It’s handy, but not enough people know about it yet. Spread the word to save people from banging their heads against the wall!

Thank you Jerry Nixon: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-animated-pie-slice.html